# Wcf with http and https endpoints

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

i have a self-hosted WCF service and trying to put another endpoint for https just for test enviroment. 
My app.config:

```
 <service name="service.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">

    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding" contract="service.IService1"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate
          storeLocation="LocalMachine"
          storeName="My"
          x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
          findValue="server"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>


  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>


</behaviors>
```

With this app.config i get the exception `“Could not find base address that matches scheme https”.` But than i put a base address like:

```
 <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8090" />
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8099" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
   <endpoint address="https://localhost:8090/secure" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding" contract="service.IService1"/>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8099/notsecure" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding" contract="service.IService1"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

And then i get other exception: `The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.`

So how can i do that? If i try to use it with only one base address and one endpoint, it could be http or https that works normally.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to define two bindings and behaviors to get that to work. Your wsHttpBinding will expect https and will complain when you have http.

Comment: @user3752226 the binding is ok, but how can i use the same behaviour for the same service?

Comment: The line <security mode="Transport"> means use HTTPS. If you want to run the service on both HTTP and HTTPS you will need to set up a second binding and set <security mode="None">

Comment: don't use base address. Just create two endpoints, the first one with **http://** (for example with basicHttpBinding) and the second one with **https://** (wsHttpBinding)